# pyqtgraph installed with micromamba using wrong Qt version

Tags: qt, pyqtgraph, mamba

I have a cascade of problems that seem to be caused by pyqtgraph import of Qt.
I created the following environment.yml file:

```
name: my-env
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - nodefaults
dependencies:
    - python=3.9
    - pydm
    - matplotlib
    - pyyaml
    - Qt>=5.15
    - pip:
        - git+https://gitlab.cnpem.br/SOL/GUI/sol-widgets@python_package
platforms:
    - linux-64
```

And i create it with:

```
micromamba env create -f environment.yml --prefix /path/to/env/my-env.
```

Finally, i try to run my application with:

```
micromamba run -p /path/to/env/my-env pydm -m "MY_MACROS" my_application.py
```

I then receive the following warning:

```
/usr/local/scripts/envs/kb-gui-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtgraph/colors/palette.py:1: RuntimeWarning: PyQtGraph supports Qt version >= 5.15, but 5.12.10 detected.
  from ..Qt import QtGui
```

Leaving the weirdness of a package complaining about a relative import inside the own package aside, i tried fixing Qt version in the environment file as seen above. Also tried fixing pyqtgraph version in environment file, but i dont know what version should i fix, if any at all.

Is there hope for me? What can i do to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Qt isn't the dependency you need to pin the version information to, it's [pyqt](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt) or [pyside2](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyside2)

Modern versions of both packages should be available from both conda-forge and defaults channels.